# How to enter Lenovo Thinkpad E570 Advanced BIOS settings?

Tags: linux, boot, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

I've been using my E570 to run Void Linux for a while now. However, I can no longer boot into my Void Linux distribution after loading BIOS Setup Defaults. I've tried toggling most of the BIOS settings, especially ones related to CPU to no avail. I recall once looking into the advanced BIOS menu and changing a CPU-related setting to allow for my Void Linux distro to boot, but now I simply do not remember how to enter the advanced menu now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Given the age of the machine it may be that you installed Linux with CSM or Compatibility Support mode enabled. With that option enabled your firmware will be emulating an old-style BIOS interface rather than the newer UEFI interface that would be "default" for most modern computers.

Check around the "Startup" for an option called "CSM Support" and see if enabling it allows you to boot. Alternatively if it is currently enabled then try disabling it.

More information can be found on page 56 of your manual: https://www.laptopsdirect.co.uk/PDFs/20H50078UK_1_3468594_Original.pdf?v=4

Comment: Not sure if still relevant but Void Linux used to have issues with Secure Boot.

Comment: Been trying with both secure boot on and off as well as with and without CSM but nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: Would anyone know how to actually toggle the CPU setting such as Multi-core Processing? I was checking over my settings on BIOS again but that did not appear.